# 赤いのかばん or 赤いなかばん? Which one is correct?

Tags: adjectives

赤いのかばん or 赤いなかばん? Which one is correct? "な" is used to connect adjective and noun, "の" is a possessive noun, but it can also be an adjective.

Answer (score 6):

Neither one is correct, I am afraid.  The correct way to say that is:

> 「赤{あか}いかばん」

because 「赤い」 is an i-adjective.

It is also correct to say:

> 「赤のかばん」

without an 「い」